# UITableView - insert rows with animation issue

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview, uiimageview

I have strange problem. In my application i have UITableView with list o comments. Cell is composed with UIImageView (background) and UITextView. For one-line comments i'm changing size (frame of UIImageView) of the background to fit the size of the text (it's called in cellForRowAtIndexPath:). It works fine for scrolling etc but when i'm changing size of the table with animation (UIView animateWithDuration:), new rows are displayed at the top and user can notice that frame of the background is also changed with animation.
Any idea how to prevent animating this background image?

[image]

Comment: provide 2 images to compare that to evaluate error

Answer (score 0):

To animate insertion of row in your table view, I suggest you to use :

```
[myTable beginUpdates];
[myTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[myTable endUpdates];
```

Where indexPathsToInsert is an array of `NSIndexPath` refering to the indexes of the rows to insert. Your data source have to be consistent before doing this update.

Comment: But i'm not inserting new rows. They are displayed because i'm increasing height of the table.